# Huge difference between Facebook Ad Click figures and Apache log requests

Tags: google-analytics, facebook, apache2, advertising

We're running a facebook ad campaign for our business but there seems to be a huge discrepancy between the number of clicks registered and the number of requests made with "facebook.com" in the HTTP referrer.

The difference can be anything between 40-80 clicks/requests.

I understand why the Google Analytics would be off and I understand that the figures shouldnt be exactly the same but surely if 100 people click the ad then I should be seeing at least 90 requests for the homepage with facebook.com as the referrer?

Can anybody provide any insight into why this may be happening?

Comment: I just got a coupon and tried running an ad on FB(2013) It seems I am getting at least 30% less clicks than FB is stating.

Comment: See also: [Less than half of Facebook ad clicks are visible in Google Analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57906/less-than-half-of-facebook-ad-clicks-are-visible-in-google-analytics)

Answer (score 1):

I think tagging the FB ad destination URL with GA tracking code is a smart move.  But I'd also consider running the campaign through a traffic auditing tool.  FB ads have acquired a reputation for being prone to fraud traffic - bots.  There was a US start-up not too long ago who found 80% of its traffic was fake.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tagged your facebook ad destination URL with Analytics tracking code so you can see that campaigns stats in Analytics? There's a discussions about this in google groups https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/analytics/discuss-google-analytics-features-with-other-users/x8AyLr_mFCc

Answer (score 0):

Most people access Facebook on secure connections nowadays (HTTPS) and in this case, the referer will not be set, as stated in the RFC:

Section 15.1.3 in RFC 2616 states:

```
Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure) HTTP
request if the referring page was transferred with a secure protocol
```

Some browsers will still send it, depending on settings (`network.http.sendSecureXSiteReferrer` in Firefox) but you should not rely on this for your analytics. Instead, you should use tagging as stated by Anagio.